# Convert single field result rows produced by "group by" to separate columns of one result row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently I get something like this (2 result rows):

```
type|totalUnits
N   | 111
E   | 67
```

But, I would like to get something like this (1 result row):

```
totalUnitsN|totalUnitsE|totalOfBothNandE
111        |67         | 178
```

Would there be some handy/recommended SQL-snippet that I could use to convert the first example to second example? Basically the first example is produced by grouping all data based on type-field and then summing about 20 columns to that one totalUnit-field. Basically I would like to keep that query as it is and then somehow convert/"merge" that data to just one row. But if the best approach for this doesn't include my current first step I could think coding this totally from the scratch as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional aggregation seems simple:

```
select sum(case when type = 'N' then totalUnits else 0 end) as totalUnits_N,
       sum(case when type = 'E' then totalUnits else 0 end) as totalUnits_E,
       sum(totalUnits) as totalUnits
from t
where type in ('N', 'E');
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I could indeed use your idea. Basically I would replace the "from" in your example with my current SQL (counting N and E totals to separate rows using group by based on type.), using it as a subquery.